# PHP scandir() but exclude certain folders

Tags: php, scandir

I found this function below here on stackoverflow however, I am trying to avoid scanning any directory with the name `includes.`

```
$dir = $_SESSION['site'];
function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()){
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {                   
           $results[] = $path;
        } else if (is_dir($path) && $value != "." && $value != ".." ) { 
            getDirContents($path, $results);
            $results[] = $path;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

I have tried adding an additional `&&` as follows:

```
} else if (is_dir($path) && $value != "." && $value != ".." && !strstr($path,"includes/")) {
```

However, this does not seem to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove trailing slash:

```
!strstr($path,"includes")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to avoid scanning any directory with the name "includes".

You could try replacing

```
$files = scandir($dir);
```

with

```
$files = preg_grep("/includes/i", scandir($dir), PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

This will result in an array of `$files` which do not contain the string "includes" using [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) and inverted matching.

> If set to PREG_GREP_INVERT, this function returns the elements of the input array that do not match the given pattern ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)).

As a bonus, you can easily customize the regular expression to add more excluded paths. Example:

```
"/includes|admin|hidden|temp|cache|^\./i"
```

This will also exclude directories that start with a `.`, so you can reduce some of your logic.

---

An alternative is

```
$files = preg_grep('/^((?!includes).)*$/i', scandir($dir));
```

This will result in an array of `$files` which do not contain the string "includes". It uses [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) and [negative look-arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) to check for "includes", and if not found, that path is included in the final array.